# sql select column that exists in multiple selects. Select values that match all values in list

Tags: sql, sqlite

This select statement:

```
select * from favoritetags where tagid = 4
```

Returns

```
ID |tagid | favoriteid |
12 |4     |12          |
50 |4     |42          |
42 |4     |34          |
```

Likewise the statement:

```
select * from favoritetags where tagid = 29
```

Returns:

```
ID |tagid | favoriteid |
49 |29    |41          |
51 |29    |34          |
```

I want to only get a list of favoriteid's that are in both.

Then I want to generalise this where I can get only those in rows that have faviriteid in common with a list of tagids. where tagid in `(29,4,6)` or any number of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select favoriteid
from favoritetags
where tag_id in (4, 29)
group by favoriteid
having count(distinct tag_id) = 2
```

The `where` clause filters on `tag_id`s that belong to the wishlist. The query aggregates by `favoriteid`, and ensures that each `favoriteid` has two distinct `tag_id`s (this actually means that both `4` and `29` are available).

This can be easily extended for more `tag_id`s:

```
select favoriteid
from favoritetags
where tag_id in (4, 29, 6)
group by favoriteid
having count(distinct tag_id) = 3
```

Comment: A variation of this seems to work for me. Where I replace id with favoriteid.

Comment: @user3371963: ah yes that’s correct I misread that part of your question. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The following query gives all the tags that have more than one occurrence in the table.

```
 SELECT * FROM #tags T JOIN 
 (
     SELECT tagid,COUNT(*) AS [Count] FROM #tags
     GROUP BY tagid
     HAVING COUNT(*)>1
  )G
   ON t.tagid=g.tagid
   ORDER BY t.tagid
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the list in a comma separated string like: `'4,29'` then use it in this statement:

```
select favoriteid
from favoritetags
where ',' || '4,29' || ',' like '%,' || tag_id || ',%' 
group by favoriteid
having count(distinct tag_id) = length('4,29') - length(replace('4,29', ',', '')) + 1
```

So the statement is:

```
select favoriteid
from favoritetags
where ',' || ? || ',' like '%,' || tag_id || ',%' 
group by favoriteid
having count(distinct tag_id) = length(?) - length(replace(?, ',', '')) + 1
```

and you replace `?` with your list.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wetHaTHMTSP97ZHeSCXbNk/1).
Or you can do it with only 1 replacement by cross joining the list:

```
select f.favoriteid
from favoritetags f cross join (select ? list) t
where ',' || t.list|| ',' like '%,' || f.tag_id || ',%' 
group by f.favoriteid
having count(distinct f.tag_id) = length(t.list) - length(replace(t.list, ',', '')) + 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wetHaTHMTSP97ZHeSCXbNk/3).
If you want the values to query in a select statement then use a `CTE` with `VALUES`:

```
with list(tag) as (values (4), (29))
select favoriteid
from favoritetags
where tag_id in (select tag from list) 
group by favoriteid
having count(distinct tag_id) = (select count(*) from list)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wetHaTHMTSP97ZHeSCXbNk/5).